# gwt/smartgwt beginner- code works correctly in dev mode, but compiled html file does not display correctly

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt2

I am working to create a simple html app using a sample from the Smart GWT Showcase, specifically from the drag and drop section.

While the html file displays correctly in dev mode, when I actually try to run it directly from the war directory, a blank screen is shown (in IE/Firefox and Chrome).

Why is this happening? How do I tackle this correctly? Do GWT/Smart GWT developers routinely face such a problem?

Comment: If we faced such a problem GWT would be a pretty useless tool wouldn't it? But your problem is likely to be either that you didn't deploy properly (are you sure you put the directory with the correct structure inside your server's expected location?) or some library that you use is not being loaded correctly. Try to enable the GWT Console logger, which logs into the browser's console, and log some messages (GWT console logger used an emulation of the java.util.logging package so it's pretty simple to use if you're familiar with Java logging).

Answer (score 1):

Many things could have gone wrong. The first thing I advise you to do is check the error console of your browser for any warnings/errors.

- Did you run the GWT compiler and did it finish correctly?
- Did it produce all the .cache.html files and *.gwt.rpc files?

Comment: The compiler finished correctly, and also produced all the files- there were no error messages. The page shows correctly in dev mode, but only the final compiled page is not showing- how do I detect what went wrong? Thanks...

Comment: Tricky... Did you inspect the DOM of the compiled page in your browser (for example with Firebug)? Especially with widgets like a TabLayoutPanel you have to set the height explicitly, or you won't see a thing.